# I'm trying to extract phone number from CommonDataKinds.Phone using contact ID from ContactsContract,Phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-contacts

The following error message is produced whenever user presses Yes button when requested permission to access contacts.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=131074, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.criminalintent/com.example.criminalintent.CrimePagerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
  com.example.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.getSuspectPhoneNumber(CrimeFragment.java:302)
   at com.example.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.updateSuspectNumber(CrimeFragment.java:322) at com.example.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(CrimeFragment.java:337)
```

The line 302 refers to query to get suspect phone number. My code to obtain the phone number from contact ID is as below.

```
private String getSuspectPhoneNumber(String contactId){
    String suspectPhoneNumber=null;

    Uri phoneContactUri= ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

    //returns columns
    String[] queryFields= new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE};

    //Selection criteria (where clause)
    String mSelectionClause= ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?";

    //Selection criteria (where args)
    String mSelectionArgs[] ={ contactId };

    //Does query and returns cursor object
    //line 302
    Cursor c= getActivity().getContentResolver().
            query(phoneContactUri,queryFields,mSelectionClause,mSelectionArgs,null);

    try {
        if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        c.moveToNext();
        int phoneType=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
        if (phoneType==ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            suspectPhoneNumber=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }
    }finally {
        c.close(); }

    return suspectPhoneNumber;}
```

The following code is a portion of onActivityResults method to get the contact/suspect name and permission for their phone number.

```
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT && data != null){
       String suspectName=getCrimeSuspect(data);
       mCrime.setSuspect(suspectName);
       mSuspectButton.setText(suspectName);

       if (hasContactsPermission()){
            updateSuspectNumber(); }
        else{
            requestPermissions(CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS,REQUEST_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS);
        }
```

Comment: please add onActivityResult() code. there will be problem.

Comment: Hi, Ive added onActivityResult method as shown above. My problem I think is that I am not sure how to use the contact Id variable to extract the phone number. 

My contact Id variable is initialized in another method to just extract the contact name an Id. However, the contact id variable in the getSuspectNumber method is null.

Comment: So,  you are getting null in getSuspectNumber?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null when no contacts are found in particular **_ID** and use onRequestPermissionsResult() instead of onActivityResult().

**Note:** please check your ReadContact permission in Manifest and also give runtime permission.

**Full Example:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 0);
            }
        } else {
            getId();
        }
    }

    //get _ID and NAME
    public void getId() {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                getNumbers(cr, id);
            }
        }
    }

    //get Numbers where ( _ID = CONTACT_ID).
    public String getNumbers(ContentResolver cr, String Id) {
        List<String> Numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{Id}, null);

        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
            String phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            int phoneType = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
            System.out.println("Contact No:==> " + phoneType);
            if (phoneType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                Numbers.add(phoneNumber);
            }
        }
        //return null when when no contacts found in specific ID otherwise it will generate error.
        if (Numbers.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Contact No:==> " + Numbers.get(0));
            return Numbers.get(0);// get number from particular index and to get all numbers set datatype String to List<String>.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            getId();
        }
    }
}
```